# Lightning - Error in $A.getCallback()

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to simulate a very simple Book Entry form using custom lightning components.

The custom object is Book__c and it has two fields Book_Author__c & Book_Name__c.

**Component markup**

```
<aura:component controller="BookController" >
    <aura:attribute name="book" type="Book__c"/>

    <div class="slds-card slds-p-top--medium">
        <header class="slds-card__header">
            <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small">Create a New Book</h3>
        </header>


    </div>

    <form class="slds-form--stacked">

    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <ui:inputText aura:id="idBookName" label="Book Name:" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element_label" value="{!v.book.Book_Name__c}"/>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:inputText aura:id="idBookAuthor" label="Book Author:" class="slds-input" labelClass="slds-form-element_label" value="{!v.book.Book_Author__c}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <ui:button label="Add New Book" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" press="{!c.AddNewBookHandler}"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</aura:component>
```

**Component Controller**

```
({
    AddNewBookHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
        var newBook = component.get("v.book");
        var action=component.get("c.saveBook");
        action.setParams({"book":newBook});
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
           var state = response.getState();
            if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS")
            {
                alert("Book Saved Successfully");

            }
            else
            {
                alert("Book Not Saved Successfully");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public class BookController {

    public static String saveBook(Book__c b)
    {
        Book__c inputBook = new Book__c();
        inputBook.Book_Author__c = b.Book_Author__c;
        inputBook.Book_Name__c = b.Book_Name__c;
        insert inputBook;
        return inputBook.Id;
    }

}
```

I am embedding the above component in an application whose markup is below

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <c:CreateBookComponent/>
</aura:application>
```

The issue is that when I do a preview of the application I am seeing multiple errors

*Error 1*

[image]

*Error 2*

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `AuraEnable` your Apex method.

Try this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String saveBook(Book__c b)
```

Also, you should add a `default` param to your attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="book" type="Book__c" 
                default="{'sobjectType:'Book__c', 'Book_Name__c': '' , 'Book_Arthur__c':''}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks  for pointing out. But still the same set of errors appear when I do a preview of the application even after adding the @AuraEnabled in the apex controller

Comment: Can you update the Apex controller method on this question? Because either you have a typo or you have not saved the code...

Comment: Make sure you refresh everything too... oh great good to hear :)